# Manage computer from active directory manager

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Within `dsa.mac` when I right-click on a computer and choose "Manage", it displays the following error message:

> Can't find path to computer \\computer.domain.tld.

If I try `ping computer.domain.tld`, DNS translates it to an IP but the computer does not answer.  It is right that ping does not answer?  Pinging a computer that is not joined to the domain replies as expected.

How can I correct this issue?

[image]

Comment: You're question is not clear it needs to be reworded. BTW, don't rely on ping as an indication that a service is up or not, most firewalls block ICMP PING these days.

Comment: I post image, but is in czech language, hope it hepls

Comment: It sounds like your Windows Firewall's Domain Profile does not allow ICMP or Windows management, or the client is offline. Can you post info about the firewall config?  Specifically, the Domain Profile.

Comment: If I try to disable firewall, then it works. What rule I must to allow when I whant to enable firewall?

Answer (score 4):

Your question isn't really clearly worded, but my guess would be that the PC you are trying to connect to is either off, unplugged from the LAN, or your ping ICMP packets are being blocked (either from a firewall on the workstation, or some other network device).

I would start by checking the PC's physical connection, then verify it's logical connection to the network.

A pretty standard pattern of tests to perform from the PC consist of:

1. Ping the loopback address (IPv4 = 127.0.0.1; IPv6 = ::1) to test the NIC
2. Ping the PC's IP Address to test TCP/IP Stack
3. Ping the Default Gateway or another IP on the same subnet to verify L2
4. Ping an IP on another subnet to verify L3
5. Ping a known PC name or the domain name to verify DNS

Comment: If I try to disable firewall, then it works. That means I must allow something on client pc firewall. Any Idea what allouw by group policy?